# Windows Server 2008 crashes

Tags: windows-server-2008

Server has crached several times this year and I can't find cause for these crashes. From minidumps I can tell only that one of processors deadlocked.
Can someone help me with this problem?

Server spec.:
OS: Windows Server 2008 SP1 x32bits
CPU: Intel Xeon 2.13Ghz x4
RAM: 4GB
Chipset: Intel Corporation 82441FX 440FX (Natoma) System Controller Rev 2 (SU053)

[Archive with minidump files](http://srv2.bce.lt/downloads/minidumps.rar)

Answer (score 0):

- check driver levels
- If driver levels are ok... return server as faulty.

Seriously. Server 2008 is dead stable. So, either you have a borked driver, or you simply have defective hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Try running some [cpu tests](http://www.pcworld.com/downloads/file/fid,7146-order,1-page,1-c,alldownloads/description.html), or [memtest](http://www.memtest.org/), see if that shows up anything... recently I had an Intel i5 CPU have problems calculating primes, nothing crashed, but the system would lock up or run very slowly - but only intermittently.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have more than one role installed on the server? It is a possibility that the roles are running in the background and using a lot of resources. Since you have 4GB of memory, you can install one additional server using hyper-v and install few roles into that server.

If this is not an issue, you can run a virus scan or malware scan using malewarebytes (note the false positive). You can also use Ultimate boot cd or Hirens boot cd to run at start up.  You can use any of these softwares to test if your CPU is functioning well.